# How to stop repetition in my code?

Tags: python, python-3.x

1. This code executes primes upto a given number. It works correctly as far as the prime generation is concerned but the output is painfully repetitive.
2. The code is:

   ```
   numP = 1
   x = 3
   y = int(input('Enter number of primes to be found: '))
   while numP<=y:
       for n in range(2, x):
           for b in range(2, n):
               if n % b == 0:
                   break
           else:
               # loop fell through without finding a factor
               print (n)
           x += 2    
       numP += 1
   ```
3. The output is like (e.g. for y=4):

   ```
   2
   2
   3
   2
   3
   5
   2 
   3
   5 
   7
   ```
4. I want to avoid repetition and obtain output like:

   ```
   2
   3 
   5 
   7
   ```
5. How should the code be modified?

Comment: Try implementing this instead: https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

Comment: you just beat me to it @larsmans, great comment

Answer (score 0):

If you store the data in a set, you will avoid repetitions

Comment: He's still recalculating all the primes up to the number every time, and the logic of "where to put the print so it happens only once per prime" is important. So is the fact that it's three loops for a two-loop problem.

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason to loop n from 2..x.  Get rid of that loop, and replace all references to 'n' with 'x'.  I.e.:

```
def find_primes(y):
    x = 3
    numP = 0
    while True:
        for b in range(2, x):
            if x % b == 0:
                break
        else:
            # loop fell through without finding a factor
            print (x)
            numP += 1
            if numP >= y:
                return
        x += 2
```